# TinyMCE input format is set to "Full HTML" but code is still being stripped

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

I am trying to enter some HTML into TinyMCE. I know that some input formats can strip code depending on your settings, but I have "Full HTML" selected, yet my code is still being stripped.

What else might be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the stripped tags in question are mostly things like embedded CSS style tags you might need to enable the [Full Page plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3afullpage) to allow them in your content, apparently having style tags in regions apart from `HEAD` tag is not the best practice and that's the reason the functionality is not enabled out of the box from my understanding. Also assuming that you have the [WYSIWYG module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg/) with TinyMCE library installed for your cause and not the [TinyMCE](http://drupal.org/project/tinymce) module, here's a sample code of how I enabled the full page plugin in my case. (The code goes in your custom module, replacing your module name with MYMODULE in the function name).

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_wysiwyg_plugin
 *
 */
function MYMODULE_wysiwyg_plugin($editor) {
  // if the editor is tinymce include the fullpage plugin so that embedded css is included
  $plugin_path = wysiwyg_get_path('tinymce');
  switch ($editor) {
    case 'tinymce':
      $plugins = array(
        'fullpage' => array(
          'path' => $plugin_path . '/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/fullpage',
          'buttons' => array('fullpage' => t('Full Page')),
          'url' => 'http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:fullpage',
          'internal' => TRUE,
          'load' => TRUE
        )
      );
      return $plugins;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```